# Unit Testing Ionic App with Cordova plugins using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

Is it possible to use Karma and Jasmine for unit testing an Ionic App with cordova plugins (e.g. sqlite, $cordovaNetwork)?

Comment: I am also struggling with this one but with Ionic 2. The only way I found out was to use the browser version of SQLite and install it as dev dependency. But this feels so bulky... It can't be the true way of testing apps involving cordova plugins. Something other that I found out was about running karma tests directly on the device. The problem with these -> you have to indicate a specific device to test on.